# can you put me after after a name like Tim and me?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

I found something that said, "Tim and me". Are you supposed to put "me" after a name? I tried to put "I" in except it won't work.

Comment: "Tim and me are _you_"? You tried to put "I" in "except"? Some punctuation would help.

Comment: Whether you use _I_ or _me_ depends on which one you would use if there was _not_ another person involved. "He invited [Tim and] me to his party." - "[Tim and] I went to the party."

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Maybe we have a new rule: "I before me except after A"? ;)

Comment: Hello Everett, and welcome to ELL! Please clarify your question using the "Edit" button. Please add the context of "Tim and me" (the full sentence, at least), and tell us what you mean by "it won't work". Do you mean a grammar checker says it's wrong??

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing, but there are two rules, that even native speakers seem to confuse.

Firstly, it is considered "more correct" to say "Tim and me" rather than "me and Tim". This is not really a question of *grammar*, but *etiquette:* if you put yourself first, you make yourself sound more important, so it is *polite* to put the name of the other person first.

This is often muddled with a different rule, about when to use "Tim and I" rather than "Tim and me", so:

> The company belongs to Tim and me

But:

> Tim and I own the company

This *is* a grammatical rule, and a very simple one: the "Tim and" doesn't change your choice of "me" or "I" - "The company belongs to me", "I own the company".

It is common informally to say "Me and Tim own the company", but that breaks *both* rules: to be *polite*, "Tim" should come first; and to be *grammatically correct*, the pronoun should be "I" not "me".

People misunderstand this, and think that you *always* have to use "Tim and I", but that is *not true* - it is what is technically known as "hypercorrection", applying a rule even when you *shouldn't*.

Comment: It would be nice to wait for the question's concern to be clarified before answering, but if we're going to, then it might be nice to highlight why you choose "I" or "me": the difference between subject and object. Kudos for pointing out the easy rule of thumb: drop the "Tim and" and see if it still "sounds right."